# Save Schema from a c1flexgrid

Tags: c#, componentone, c1flexgrid

I have a c1flexgrid form component one that gets data from a datatable. The user Is allowed to change the order of the columns.

My Question is, is it possible to safe the schema of the flexgrid, so that the user can load it
the next time he open the Programm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save the flexgrid [WinForms] information. Try using the **SaveGrid**/**LoadGrid** methods to save/load the grid information.

FlexGrid exposes many forms of saving/loading the data/information. To learn more about them the following documentation section should help: https://www.grapecity.com/componentone/docs/win/online-flexgrid/savingloadingandprinting.html

P.S.: GrapeCity has platform specific public forums as well to discuss such requirements. See: https://www.grapecity.com/forums

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27038807)

Comment: @Jbadminton I got your point. However, the answer (using the SaveGrid/LoadGrid methods) to the question is already included in the response and yes, the URL is only for reference.